# Не работает код C++ в VS 2010, а в VS 2008 пашет! В чём причина? Поможете?

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте!
Прохожу обучение по C++. У учителя на мониторе код в VS 2008 работает, у меня в VS 2010 не работает. Проверял, всё написано правильно(т.е. как у учителя).

Сам код(разбита на 3 файла):

```
//Определение класса Point
#ifndef POINT_H
#define POINT_H

class Point
{
private:            
    int x, y;
public:
    int GetX() {return x;} //inline по умолчанию
    int GetY();
    void SetX(int);
    void SetY(int);

};

inline int Point::GetY() { return y; }

#endif
```

2 файл:

```
//Реализация класса Point

#include"Point.h"

void SetX(int _x)
{
     x = _x >= 0 ? _x : 0;

}

void SetY(int _y)
{

    y = _y >= 0 ? _y : 0;

}
```

3 файл:

```
//Использованиие класса Point (клиентский код)
#include<iostream>

#include"Point.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Point a;
    a.SetX(10);
    a.SetY(20);

    cout << a.GetX() << ", " << a.GetY() << endl;

    system("pause");
}
```

Код ошибки отладчика VS 2010:

```
1>------ Построение начато: проект: Point, Конфигурация: Debug Win32 ------
1>Построение начато 21.01.2012 21:14:51.
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Обращение к "Debug\Point.unsuccessfulbuild".
1>ClCompile:
1>  usePoint.cpp
1>  Point.cpp
1>c:\users\vladislav\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\point\point.cpp(9): error C2065: x: необъявленный идентификатор
1>c:\users\vladislav\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\point\point.cpp(16): error C2065: y: необъявленный идентификатор
1>  Создание кода...
1>
1>СБОЙ построения.
1>
1>Затраченное время: 00:00:00.55
========== Построение: успешно: 0, с ошибками: 1, без изменений: 0, пропущено: 0 ==========
```

Что может являться причиной? Проект консольный(пустой).

Благодарен за помощь. Спасибо.

Comment: Вопрос закрыт. Решение в 1-ом ответе.
Всем спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В файле "point.cpp" вместо

```
void SetX(int _x)
```

нужно написать

```
void Point::SetX(int _x)
```

Тоже самое с игреком.

Такой код не должен был компилироваться. Вы что-то упустили при переписывании.

Comment: Теперь другая ошибка:
1>c:\users\vladislav\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\point\point.cpp(7): error C2039: SetX: не является членом "`global namespace'"
1>c:\users\vladislav\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\point\point.cpp(13): error C2039: SetY: не является членом "`global namespace'"

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, а с чем это связанно? Почему у меня не работало, а у учителя работало?

Comment: Такой код не должен был работать у учителя. Вы что-то упустили.

Comment: Быть может, просто я через скайп на чужом вебинаре :).

Comment: Такой код вообще не должен работать ни у кого и никогда. Что-то очень странное. Задайте лучше этот вопрос Вашему учителю.